# Inter-state Fighting

Tags: warfare

The United States of America has 50 states and 14 territories (according to Google). In my story, each state is drawn far apart from each other due to conflicting interests. If all 50 states + 14 territories went to war against each other, which state would win?

Conditions: I am talking about militaristic winning. The exact details, I'm not sure. I would prefer it to be conquering all other states, but I'm not sure if that is entirely possible.

Time Period: Current

Methods of fighting: Everything each state has, EXCEPT for nuclear war. So states with nuclear missiles would NOT have an advantage.

*Could you guys include specific details and facts? Thanks :D*

Comment: Please help me improve my question, as the specific part of the question (what is the definition of winning?) doesn't really make sense and is not specific.

Comment: did "dotard" fired everybody in the federal congress?

Comment: The United States of America has 50 states and 14 territories... and the largest and most powerful army in the world. The U. S. army *does not* belong to the states; it belongs to the U. S. The last time a bunch of states tried to break away due to conflicting interests the U. S. army objected. The military forces of the states are vastly insufficient to overpower the U. S. army.

Comment: I think we need to know the conditions of the collapse. Following onto @AlexP comment, you have to tell us how the Fed gov't got out of the way.

Comment: The U.S. Military has been *specifically designed* with it's own checks and balances (updated most notably in 1916, 1948, and 1973) to be an interdependent --part national, part state-- organization, with neither the President nor the Governors controlling too much during peacetime. Example: Over 50% of Army combat power is in the National Guard, but all Army ammunition production is by DOD.

Comment: As written who would win is simply opinion based.  @AlexP makes an excellent point about this as [the US military swears allegiance to the US Constitution](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/oath-of-enlistment-3354049), not to States.  And note that part in the oath about "enemies both foreign *and* domestic".  So what happened the Federal Government is rather significant in this context, and especially whether a US Armed Forces exists and considered itself still guardian of the US Constitution is important to your question.

Comment: Are other countries allowed to intervene in the war?

Comment: @Vincent No. I see how this question is too opinion-based. I apologize

Comment: You should have asked this 110 years ago, when Army Divisions were still State/region-based.  That was changed WW1.

Comment: "Please help me improve my question" - forgive me, but isn't that what the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) is for? I feel like you should have posted this there first, especially if you knew it needed work.

Comment: @F1Krazy Sigh...I haven't been here long enough to know that one existed :(

Answer (score 2):

Conflicts like this depend on an enoremous number of issues.  This is true when there's two sides.  When there's many individual nations engaging in an all out brawl, [it's even more complicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WgT9gy4zQA).

A big question would be what alliances form.  Obviously there's a desire to not ally with your enemy, but when your option is forming an alliance or getting blown away, alliances form.

All those complexities aside, I'd point out that California, Texas, and Virgina have [more military bases](http://www.militarybases.us/by-state/) than the other states.  It's not a 1:1 mapping to success, but it certainly means they will have the resources to engage in a fight.

EDIT: SRM brings up an interesting point.  Obviously *how* this predicament occurs will have a tremendous impact on the behavior of our armed forces.  And, to StephenG's comment, this is the oath sworn to by the enlisted forces of the United States (emphasis mine):

> I, (NAME), do solemnly swear (or affirm) that I will support and defend the Constitution of the United States against all enemies, foreign and domestic; that I will bear true faith and allegiance to the same; **and that I will obey the orders of the President of the United States and the orders of the officers appointed over me**, according to regulations and the Uniform Code of Military Justice. So help me God.

It'd be a heck of a complicated situation to untangle!

Comment: The soldiers on those bases hail from all 50 states. Are you sure that the Kentucky commander is going to fight for Texas just because he is at Ft. Hood?

Comment: Good point on alliances; there was never a point in history with more than 3 sides in a conflict. And good point on out-of-state troops. Even if state governors order troops on their territory to go fight each other, current military will just depose them and establish nationwide military rule (and hopefully hold new elections soon). Military members will act on loyalties to each other, and then to their home state.

Comment: When the Quebec separatists in Canada nearly won an election,  part of their calculation was based on Quebec having more military bases than the rest of Canada,  and the requirement that soldiers be bilingual french and English meant that most of the military hailed from Quebec. They didn't count on the military having just returned from policing the outcome of separatism in Bosnia, and wanting nothing to do with such a mess at home.

Comment: Many of Virginia's bases are for research, administration, etc.  Housing a *lot* of low-paid infantry enlisted men in *expensive* Virginia doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Why assume that each state would remain a unified entity?  California would likely split into at least 3 mutually hostile entities, two of them aligning with northern & southern Nevada.  Upstate New York would separate from NYC...

Comment: @jamesqf NYC itself could split on all sorts of cultural, political and racial divides, as could LA.  Once the sense of unity goes it could be utter chaos.  And who would the police forces align with ( Fed, State, local or themselves ) ?  What a mess !